# How is right to format and validate edit control to accept only float or currency values

Tags: delphi, validation, formatting

I have a application that needs to accept float or currency values in edit control. My question is what I must to do to format and validate edit controls input so it accepts only numbers, comma or dot (comma or dot depends on system locale). And the formatting is ##.## (45.21). I want to do one method that can control all edit controls wehre float formatting and validating is used.

Right now I have code in OnChange event that uses TryStrToFloat method, but sometimes I get "'' is not floating point number" errors.

Maybe you guys have done it more than me and have some great examples how to do it right.

Comment: @evilone By edit control you mean TEdit?

Comment: OK, you don't like `TMaskEdit`. I'm sure there are variants out there that would be more to your liking.

Comment: You can replace the placeholder character ("_" by default) by any character, e.g. whitespace (" "), by changing the last argument in the `EditMask`.

Comment: @David I don't said that I don't like it. I said I'm not familiar with and I don't know how to use it. So please teach me!

Comment: @evilone I don't really know it. I don't like validation as you type myself. I prefer to validate as late as possible.

Comment: +1 for late validation aka don't bother your user's for being humans.

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to show to user annoying messageboxes all the time if there has been some typing mistake.

Comment: @evilone In a totally ideal world, I'd go for a two-pronged approach. Validate as the user types, but display feedback by setting the edit background red when the input is not valid (only do this after, say, 1s idle time). Only show error dialogs when they click OK on the modal dialog. For my forms validation is very hard because it often depends on other values on the form and quite often on values on other forms. So I just leave it as late as possible and assume that my users know what they are doing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to continue using the same validation approach, just enhance your algorithm to consider the edge cases (and how you want to manage that).

For example, you can consider accepting an empty string as a valid input and just don't throw an exception, or not.  You must also consider how do you want to perform the user interaction in case of malformed input.  For example if a user enters a invalid number, you want to stop the user to input values at that same millisecond... or you can take a more natural approach (for example, validating until the user thinks everything is correct).

You can also manage validation just by notifying the user in a non-stoper way while the input is being done, just making a visible effect over the offending fields, and in a stopper way (for example with a message box) if the user tries to save the data.

A simple validation function may look like this:

```
function IsEditValidFloat(Sender: TEdit; const AcceptBlank: Boolean = True): Boolean;
var
  sValue: string;
  Temp: Extended;
begin
  sValue := Trim(Sender.Text);
  if (sValue.Text = '') then
    Result := AcceptBlank
  else
    Result := TryStrToFloat(sValue, Temp);
end;

//you might call this on the OnChangeEvent:
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if IsEditValidFloat(Sender as TEdit) then
    ChangeDisplayState(Sender, dsValid)
  else
    ChangeDisplayState(Sender, dsError);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get the [JVCL](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/) and use the [TJvValidateEdit](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help%3aTJvValidateEdit) component.