# Why does the following code result in missing operator or semicolon compilation error?

Tags: delphi

I have the following code in a form:

```
procedure TForm1.RoundClick(Sender: TObject);
var   
  Number : real;            

begin
  rNumber := Number.Value;
  ShowMessage('Round(rNumber) = '+FloatToStr(Round(rNumber)));  
end;
```

This results in the following compiler error:

> [Error] Unit1.pas(39): Missing operator or semicolon

I don't see any missing semicolons and I don't know where to put an operator, the error is at my `rNumber`.

Comment: You are going to have to give us an example of input and output, because your question is not making sense.

Comment: You are asking for code, aren't you? what have you tried so far?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just want a single function, where the user inputs a single number (let's say 123.456) and then calculate `Trunc`, `Round`, and `Frac` on that number, and display the result to the user? Yes, of course there's a way. Technically, that is the answer to your question. However, you probably meant to ask how to do so. However, when it comes to, for example, rounding, how do you intend to round? Up? Down? Nearest? Banker's rounding? How many digits? Integers, Doubles, or Currency?

Comment: I added just a short code it does exactly the same with Trunc , Round and Frac, I'm wanting to Round to the nearest whole number , so if  I type in ex. 10,7 Round should automatically round it to the nearest whole number which is in this case 11

Comment: You did not define the variable rnumber?

Comment: @whosrdaddy I fixed the rNumber sorry about that but now it gives me an error ' Project1.exe raised exceptions class EConvertError with message ''3.5' is not a valid integer value' Process stopped . I'm fairly new to Delphi and I was using a SpinEdit to type in the number (x) I would like to round off , is there any other component I can use in Delphi to type only a number in like SpinEdit

Comment: See [How is right to format and validate edit control to accept only float or currency values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5033078/576719) and [Detect if string contains a float?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20229105/576719).

Comment: And please note that you are supposed to ask one question. If you have another question, create a new question. But first fix this question by adding the variable definition of `rNumber`.

Comment: Please fix your question and put all the code in you have right now, don't make us guess...

Comment: `Real` type got a helper, or what is that `Value` member ?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your class has a button whose name is `Round`. So when you write `Round(...)`, the compiler sees `Round` as a button rather than a function.

You can do either of the following:

1. Rename the button to avoid the name clash.
2. Use a fully qualified name to resolve the name clash. In this case you would write `System.Round` because the `Round` function is defined in the `System` unit.